# ES6 array initialization

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Very new to ES6.
In ES5  I might do something like this

```
function newArray(){
   var data = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    data[i] = "test data " + i;   
   }
  return data;
}

x = newArray()
```

How would I do this in ES6 ? What I've got below is in error

```
 getData = () => ({
    let data = Array.from(new Array(5), (x, i) => "test data " + i)
    return {
        data
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: unexpected token ^ let data. It's my ES6 syntax that in error. not sure what to do

Comment: the issue is the outer `()` after the `=>` ... surrounding {} with () makes {} an object literal, which means you have an invalid syntax for an object literal

Answer (score 2):

You create wrong the function with `ES6`

```js
getData = () =>{
    let data = Array.from(new Array(5), (x, i) => "test data " + i)
    return {
        data
    };
}
console.log(getData())
```

You can fill an `array` using `fill` and `map` methods.

```js
//arr.fill(value, start, end)
getData = () =>{
    let data = new Array(5).fill(0).map((a,i)=>"test data " + i);
    return {
        data
    };
}
console.log(getData())
```

Comment: @Rory, don't forget to accept one answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 it should be something like this:

```js
const data = Array.from(new Array(5), (x, i) => "test data " + i);
// if you want to return an object with the field data mapped to your array
const getData2 = () => ({ data });
console.log(getData2());
```

Comment: OP seems to want `getData` to return an object... not sure why.