# Reserve an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In many programming languages an array can reserve a number of elements which allocates some amount of memory in advance to improve performance when adding elements to an array. Is there some equivalent in Javascript to do that kind of optimisation?

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469583/es6-array-initialization/43469647

Comment: JavaScript has sparse arrays, meaning that this is not really possible.

Comment: If you look at the array size in different usecases, you'll see that engines might do that for you. How arrays look like in memory is not specified, and as such this is engine dependent and cannot be influenced by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the array constructor with a single argument:

```js
const arr = new Array(10); // now has 10 empty slots
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array). Both V8 and Spidermonkey (Chrome and Firefox's engines, respectively) receive a noticeable performance boost when preallocating the array. I have not tested on other engines.

Comment: How does this improve performance however and by how much?

Comment: This creates a sparse array and doesn't allocate anything in advance. Meaning no performance improvement whatsoever.

Comment: While in **theory** there is no improvement, V8 is a magical beast that aggressively optimizes pre-allocated arrays. See the test suite [here](https://jsbench.me/67kems3h2u/1) and my benchmarks (in chrome) [here](https://imgur.com/a/nScJ0Cy).

Comment: I have just tested with firefox (spidermonkey) and added the results to the album. Preallocating an array is still faster than not allocating an array, however first assigning to the 100th element is faster than preallocating an array. I'm going to continue testing to see if there's a way to get a uniform performance boost across both engines.

Comment: @Aplet123 ok this is at least something, when some engines can use this to optimise. As asked before, do you know for which engines this applies?

Comment: Both V8 and Spidermonkey (Chrome and Firefox's engines, respectively) receive a noticeable performance boost when preallocating the array. I have not tested on other engines.

Comment: This does not answer the question, does it? At least add the considerations done here in the comments to the answer, maybe also include references to specific implementations, e.g. https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/f20a63d1bf0dce4506116bc36b4728755ea47f3a/src/objects/js-array.h#L109